# Cannot start a server on Rails with PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, server

I'm making an address book app and my reequipments are to use postgres as a database. Installing and setting up has gone smoothly but for some reason when I go to start the server I get this error message "connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied"

this is my database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode

  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: scafold_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: scafold_test
  username: scafold
  password: 

production:
  <<: *default
  database: scafold_production
  username: scafold
  password: <%= ENV["SCAFOLD_DATABASE_PASSWORD"] %>
```

I've tried searching everywhere for my specific problem, but I cannot find a solution. Please help.

Comment: “Installing and setting up has gone smoothly”. Where have you installed and setup your PSQL database? Before you can connect to it, you need to create the psql instance itself. Have you done anything for that yet?

Comment: I have set up a databse throught the pgadmin 4

Comment: You’re presumably connecting to your development environment? Have you not setup a username/password?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you haven’t actually created your postgresql instance, there are a couple ways you can go about doing so:

My personal go to method is using a docker-compose file and the corresponding `docker compose up -d` command to startup the container.

Something like:

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml

version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres_db
```

```yaml
# path/to/database.yml

<< ENVIRONMENT_TYPE_HERE >>:
    url: postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/postgres_db?schema=public&connection_limit=5
```